# NameError no django, mas a classe ta definida

Tags: python, django

Ao rodar o `python3 manage.py runsserver` eu recebo o erro :

```html
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/savio/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/savio/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/savio/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 77, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/home/savio/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/home/savio/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/savio/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/savio/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home/savio/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/savio/Downloads/proGEN-master/progen/apps/cargas/models/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .romaneio import *
  File "/home/savio/Downloads/proGEN-master/progen/apps/cargas/models/romaneio.py", line 22, in <module>
    class VisualizarRomaneio(Carga):
NameError: name 'Carga' is not defined
```

Mas o name Carga está definido, e ele não libera:

```html
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import date
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

from decimal import Decimal

from progen.apps.fiscal.models import PIS, COFINS
from progen.apps.estoque.models import DEFAULT_LOCAL_ID

import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')

STATUS_CARGA_ESCOLHAS = (
    (u'0', u'Aberto'),
    (u'1', u'Faturado'),
    (u'2', u'Cancelado'),
)

class VisualizarRomaneio(Carga):
    carga = models.ForeignKey(
        'vendas.OrcamentoVenda', related_name="orcamento_pedido",
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    data_entrega = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=1, choices=STATUS_CARGA_ESCOLHAS, default='0')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Romaneio"
        permissions = (
            ("ver_romaneio", "Pode visualizar romaneios"),
        )

    @property
    def format_data_entrega(self):
        return '%s' % date(self.data_entrega, "d/m/Y")

    @property
    def tipo_romaneio(self):
        return 'Romaneio'

    def edit_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('vendas:editarpedidovendaview', kwargs={'pk': self.id})

    def __unicode__(self):
        s = u'Romaneio nº %s (%s)' % (
            self.id, self.get_status_display())
        return s

    def __str__(self):
        s = u'Romaneio nº %s (%s)' % (
            self.id, self.get_status_display())
        return s


class Carga(models.Model):
   # Pedido
    pedido = models.ForeignKey(
        'vendas.Venda', related_name="venda_pedido", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ind_final = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    # Transporte
    transportadora = models.ForeignKey(
        'cadastro.Transportadora', related_name="venda_transportadora", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    veiculo = models.ForeignKey('cadastro.Veiculo', related_name="venda_veiculo",
                                on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    # Info
    data_emissao = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    vendedor = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    valor_total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=13, decimal_places=2, validators=[
                                      MinValueValidator(Decimal('0.00'))], default=Decimal('0.00'))

    @property
    def format_data_emissao(self):
        return '%s' % date(self.data_emissao, "d/m/Y")

    def get_valor_total_attr(self, nome_attr):
        valor_total = 0
        for item in self.itens_venda.all():
            v = getattr(item, nome_attr, 0)
            if v:
                valor_total += v

        return valor_total

    def __unicode__(self):
        s = u'Romaneio nº %s' % (self.id)
        return s

    def __str__(self):
        s = u'Romaneio nº %s' % (self.id)
        return s
```

Answer (score 0):

A classe `Carga` está definida no seu código depois da classe `VisualizarRomaneio`(classe que herda `Carga`). Em Python você só pode herdar classes criadas antes. Para corrigir este problema, escreva a classe `Carga` antes de `VisualizarRomaneio`, dessa forma:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import date
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

from decimal import Decimal

from progen.apps.fiscal.models import PIS, COFINS
from progen.apps.estoque.models import DEFAULT_LOCAL_ID

import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')

STATUS_CARGA_ESCOLHAS = (
    (u'0', u'Aberto'),
    (u'1', u'Faturado'),
    (u'2', u'Cancelado'),
)

class Carga(models.Model):
   # Pedido
    pedido = models.ForeignKey(
        'vendas.Venda', related_name="venda_pedido", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ind_final = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    # Transporte
    transportadora = models.ForeignKey(
        'cadastro.Transportadora', related_name="venda_transportadora", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    veiculo = models.ForeignKey('cadastro.Veiculo', related_name="venda_veiculo",
                                on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    # Info
    data_emissao = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    vendedor = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    valor_total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=13, decimal_places=2, validators=[
                                      MinValueValidator(Decimal('0.00'))], default=Decimal('0.00'))

    @property
    def format_data_emissao(self):
        return '%s' % date(self.data_emissao, "d/m/Y")

    def get_valor_total_attr(self, nome_attr):
        valor_total = 0
        for item in self.itens_venda.all():
            v = getattr(item, nome_attr, 0)
            if v:
                valor_total += v

        return valor_total

    def __unicode__(self):
        s = u'Romaneio nº %s' % (self.id)

class VisualizarRomaneio(Carga):
    carga = models.ForeignKey(
        'vendas.OrcamentoVenda', related_name="orcamento_pedido",
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    data_entrega = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=1, choices=STATUS_CARGA_ESCOLHAS, default='0')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Romaneio"
        permissions = (
            ("ver_romaneio", "Pode visualizar romaneios"),
        )

    @property
    def format_data_entrega(self):
        return '%s' % date(self.data_entrega, "d/m/Y")

    @property
    def tipo_romaneio(self):
        return 'Romaneio'

    def edit_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('vendas:editarpedidovendaview', kwargs={'pk': self.id})

    def __unicode__(self):
        s = u'Romaneio nº %s (%s)' % (
            self.id, self.get_status_display())
        return s

    def __str__(self):
        s = u'Romaneio nº %s (%s)' % (
            self.id, self.get_status_display())
        return s
```